# Shortcut for Resizing Windows

Tags: vim

The code snippet in `~/.vimrc` below used to work. Somewhere down the line it stopped working but I can't place the interfering code nor can I tell when it broke. Grepping in `~/.vim` for `<C-left>` shows nothing....

Removed all plugged plugins, still didn't work. This makes me think it is something in the `~/.vimrc` that is causing the issue... However all additional `~/.vim` files are located in the linked repo.

```
" resize current buffer by +/- 5
    nnoremap <C-left> :vertical resize -5<cr>
    nnoremap <C-down> :resize +5<cr>
    nnoremap <C-up> :resize -5<cr>
    nnoremap <C-right> :vertical resize +5<cr>
```

Any ideas what is breaking this?

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gutelfuldead/dotfiles/master/files/vimrc

Comment: Are you using Vim in tmux?

Comment: ...........YES but it still doesn't work outside of tmux I had the same thought.

Comment: Removed everything from ~/.vimrc except the lines in the question, no difference.... Removed ~/.vim, no difference. Is the syntax wrong and I mistakenly modified it somewhere? Looks like another application may be in the way...?

Comment: @gutelfuldead, I have created [this plugin](https://github.com/Aster89/WinZoZ) which could be very helpful to you, I believe. It gives you a "window-mode" in which you can easily resize and move windows.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was `nnoremap` should have been `noremap`. Also had to swap the `+`/`-` signs.

Functional,

```
" resize current buffer by +/- 5
noremap <C-left> :vertical resize +5<cr>
noremap <C-down> :resize -5<cr>
noremap <C-up> :resize +5<cr>
noremap <C-right> :vertical resize -5<cr>
```